# how to avoid square brackets from url after unquote

Tags: python, url, urllib

i've decided to add a querystring on URL like this

```
import urllib
import urllib.parse
from urllib.parse import urlencode

url = "https://datausa.io/api/data?Geography=04000US06&drilldowns=Race,Ethnicity&measures=Hispanic%20Population,Hispanic%20Population%20Moe"
parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
query_dict = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parts.query)  
query_dict['Geography'] = '04000US24'
new_parts = list(parts)
new_parts[4] = urlencode(query_dict)
print(urllib.parse.urlunparse(new_parts))
```

and i got this result

https://datausa.io/api/data?Geography=04000US24&drilldowns=%5B%27Race%2CEthnicity%27%5D&measures=%5B%27Hispanic+Population%2CHispanic+Population+Moe%27%5D

and so this url didn't work anymore. So i used unquote, like this

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
url = unquote('https://datausa.io/api/data?Geography=04000US24&drilldowns=%5B%27Race%2CEthnicity%27%5D&measures=%5B%27Hispanic+Population%2CHispanic+Population+Moe%27%5D')
print(url)
```

but got this

```
https://datausa.io/api/data?Geography=04000US24&drilldowns=['Race,Ethnicity']&measures=['Hispanic+Population,Hispanic+Population+Moe']
```

and this url doesn't work too.

How can i remove square brackets an come back to original url
https://datausa.io/api/data?Geography=04000US24&drilldowns=Race,Ethnicity&measures=Hispanic%20Population,Hispanic%20Population%20Moe  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `doseq` parameter.

```py
new_parts[4] = urlencode(query_dict, doseq=True)
```

See the docs on [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) for more information on the parameter